# What is the algorithm behind np.linalg.solve?

Tags: python, numpy

I am supposed to compare the efficiency between different methods to solve a system of linear equations in python. One of the methods I used was `np.linalg.solve`.

I have been trying to find the algorithm that python uses but I couldn't really find any helpful information.
I was wondering if anyone could explain this to me or let me know where I can find information about algorithms of python functions that are more than just the documentation (meaning for example what kind of wrapper is it and for what, etc.).

Comment: Did you read https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html already?

Comment: Even if we told you (by name), would it mean anything to you?  What do you know about linear equation solvers?  What level of detail do you need?  What methods are you supposed to compare?

Comment: https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node71.html

Comment: @hpaulj We learned methods like PLU decomposition, gaussian elimination, matrix inversion. I believe my problem is the programming part, finding out which method is used. I am supposed to compare PLU decomposition and later solving of the triangular matrices, Inversion of a matrix and then a 'general' method like the linalg.solve. So my next question would be, if the difference between linalg.solve and implementing PLU myself is that linalg.solve solves the system without saving information in the process compared to when I do it and save e.g. the decomposition?

Comment: You might want to stick with the `scipy.linalg` interfaces - for a consistent interface to the underlying standard libraries.  Looks like the default `scipy.linalg.solve` uses the same GESV.  Beware that there's a big difference between doing something on your own in interpreted python and using an interface to a compiled, and highly optimized public library like LAPACK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually all packages especially numpy have a **documentation** for each of their functions. So let's have a look there.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

Awesome, they explain all their input arguments, and even have an example. For your purposes (understanding the algorithm), there is this sweet section on **references**.

*G. Strang, Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 2nd Ed., Orlando, FL, Academic Press, Inc., 1980, pg. 22.*

And if we google it we are lucky enough to find that this is not behind a pay-wall. For example you can get the pdf [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tadeusz-Ostrowski/post/Dear-researchers-Can-any-one-suggest-to-me-good-books-in-matrix-analysis-random-matrix-theory-linear-algebra-and-probability-theory/attachment/59d62a7a79197b8077988e2d/AS%3A339265402753024%401457898583820/download/Strang.pdf) - because we are tracing the page information they have given, we need to make sure to get the same edition of the book, otherwise we need a little bit more searching later on. Now you either can understand this and are happy, or you are able to ask more precise questions.

But there is more, again following the **documentation** you will usually find something like [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.26.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L329-L411), which will show you the way to the **implementation** of exactly the function you are interested in. Sure they are using other functions again, such as:

```
from numpy.linalg import _umath_linalg
```

Comment: Going further down that hole, you'll get to the documentation for the LAPACK gesv solver https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html.